# Color palettes to a list for xslxwriter plots line color

Tags: python, matplotlib, xlsxwriter, color-palette

I've been searching around for an answer to this. Is there a way to pull a color palette from matplotlib colormap palette for example and put those RGB color codes into a list?

Answer (score 1):

If `cmap` is a matplotlib colormap, you get all colors from it via

```
cmap(numpy.arange(cmap.N).astype(int))
```